# How to get Django to work on Apache in Windows?

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

I'm creating an internet radio station site on my Apache, and I've decided Django is the CMS which is best suited to the task.

http://www.gareth53.co.uk/work.html mentions it being used for radio station sites, and I decided I'd go with this since it seems to be a fairly popular choice.

These are some examples of it in action on live sites:

http://www.capitalfm.com/on-air/station-schedule/

http://www.heart.co.uk/suffolk/shows/

I'm aware I need python and mod_wsgi to get it to run, but how do I ensure it works properly on an Apache server? (I'm on Vista Home Edition, and this is just a test/development site until it works properly).

I want my schedules page to look similar to this CMS:

http://www.trentfm.co.uk/schedule.asp

(the effect I'm trying to emulate, in design terms).

I'm aware I'd have to create templates from reading the Django manual, and it uses SQLite, but I'm fairly new to Django and it would be a useful skill to learn.

Obviously that site uses IIS, which I'm not using, but the design is what I am intending to create a homage to (under copyright law a parody etc. **is** permissible under fair use - the station names are different, though).

My site is different, but the same basic model applies as seen in the stations above.

What has been your experience of using Django and would you recommend it as a CMS?

Comment: You are mixing too many questions here. Focus on one specific issue; in this case, edit your question to leave out anything not related to "how to get Django to work on Apache on Windows?".

Comment: If you're really looking for a CMS, I doubt Django is "best suited for the task", given that it's not a CMS. If you *do* want a CMS, look at the http://www.django-cms.org/.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Django is not a CMS.. it is a web framework. You can find how to deploy django with apache and modwsgi in the following link.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/